# Implement custom template (static web - HTML) on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have an static (HTML) web template and I just want to implement that template on WordPress but I don't know who to do that..
Kindly help me 
Thanks...

Comment: It is a long and painful road my friend. But without seeing your template or knowing what version of WP you intend to use, it is very hard to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates

http://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_Design_and_Layout#Themes_and_Templates

http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

http://codex.wordpress.org/Designing_Themes_for_Public_Release